# PHP: YouTube Data API returns no channel on "Playlists.list" but on "Channels.list"

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm not sure if this is an inconsistency of YouTube's Data API or just a bad naming of a YouTube error.

There's a public channel on YouTube without any content:

`https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvAHk_1_TMmq6SW0XA9BcgA`.

If I query [`Channels:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) ([query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22UCvAHk_1_TMmq6SW0XA9BcgA%22%5D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22items(status%2Cid%2Csnippet(title))%22%7D)) with this channel ID `UCvAHk_1_TMmq6SW0XA9BcgA`, I get the following response:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "UCvAHk_1_TMmq6SW0XA9BcgA",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "level10store0"
      },
      "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "public",
        "isLinked": true,
        "longUploadsStatus": "longUploadsUnspecified"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I query for all playlists of this channel via [`Playlists:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) ([query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCvAHk_1_TMmq6SW0XA9BcgA%22%7D)) I get this response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
  "etag": "iziRvpOe3rkNWHlySTxLgAk4dJI",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": []
}
```

But using YouTube's PHP client with `Playlist:list` you'll get a response error with following information:

> domain=youtube.playlist,  reason=channelNotFound,  location=channelId,
> locationType=parameter

Why does YouTube's PHP client give a `channelNotFound` error instead of an empty response like YouTube's data explorer does?

**Update 1:**
YouTube's data API delivered a channel on the OAuth handshake initialized by the user itself. My application asked for an offline access token for further requests. If I use this access token I experience the above mentioned behaviour. I think the token is valid as I use the identical process for many other users. If the token would not be valid I would have got an error message like *global.authError* or *youtube.header.youtubeSignupRequired*.

My code looks like this (which works for many other users):

```php
$youtubeClient->playlists->listPlaylists(
    'snippet,contentDetails',
     array(
        'maxResults' => 50,
        'channelId' => $channelId,
        'pageToken' => $nextPlaylistPageToken,
        'fields' => 'etag,items(id,etag,snippet(publishedAt,channelId,thumbnails/default,title),contentDetails(itemCount)),nextPageToken'
    )
);
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @ninsky: a bare `wget` command calling the `Playlists.list` API endpoint with request parameters exactly as yours produces the following JSON response text: `{"etag":"...","items":[]}`. The behavior you're experiencing may well be a bug of the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). Which version do you use? The latest is v2.8.3. (Sorry, I myself cannot run PHP at the moment.)

Comment: @ninsky: I issued `wget` to call `Playlists.list` endpoint using an API key and, separately, a valid access token. Both type of calls return back the same kind of JSON text (as mentioned above).

Comment: @stvar, I'm using the lastest version v2.8.3. Think I should open a bug ticket somewhere pointing to this stackoverflow question. I will post it here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: See here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/2026

Comment: @ninsky: You may also file a bug report to Google's [own issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/), mentioning also the issue you've opened on Github. (I don't know how active are they resolving issues posted on Github.)

Comment: @stvar, your linked bug report is similar to [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138008530) which I've created some time ago. But [here the bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177190637) to this stackoverlow issue

Comment: @ninsky: Sorry, this was my mistake; my link above is misleading. I deleted that comment (since not allowed to edit it).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that YouTube is channel based and not user based.   When the user logs in they pick which channel to access.  When the user consented access to your application on PHP they did not pick the correct channel so there for do not have access to the data on that channel.

Log the user out and consent access again this time picking the correct channel.

Comment: Hello DalmTo, I'm aware of this logic. But I think it's not related to my issue because I've got a channel once which I've persisted with a access token. See my update 1.